# Is there a way to check for a word within cell?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to check if a cell contains text in Google Apps Script and Google Sheets.

```
var cell = "Joe, Bob, Tim, John"

//I would want this to execute
if(cell contains "Tim") {
//code
}
```

Comment: You can use `split()` to make it an array then use the `includes()` methods.

Comment: @Xp.L Google Apps Script doesn't include built-in support of `includes()`, so a polyfill is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently, a `TextFinder` class was has been added to the `SpreadsheetApp` service that allows you to do this on a live `Range` (or `Sheet` or even a `Spreadsheet` itself). See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) for more details. Simply set the finder on a context with a `createTextFinder()` with the text you want to find as an argument.
Calling a `findNext()` method on the resulting `TextFinder` instance will either return the `Range` it was called on or `null` if nothing was found. For example:

```
function findText() {

  var sh = getSheet(); //custom function that returns target Sheet;
  var rng = sh.getRange(1,1); //change to desired Range boundaries;

  //create TextFinder and configure;
  var tf = rng.createTextFinder('textToFind');
      tf.matchCase(false); //{Boolean} -> match target text's case or not;
      tf.matchEntireCell(false); //{Boolean} -> check the whole Range or within;
      tf.ignoreDiacritics(true); //{Boolean} -> ignore diacretic signs during match;
      tf.matchFormulaText(false); //{Boolean} -> search in formulas (if any) or values;

  //invoke search;
  var res = tf.findNext();

  //do something with result;
  if(res!==null) {
    var vals = res.getValues();
    Logger.log(vals);
  }

}
```